# How to display page url without /index.html?

Tags: ruby, jekyll, liquid

I'm new to jekyll and liquid and I'm having a problem with the canocial url. On the post (article) page, everything works perfectly. But on category pages, /index.html is added to the url.

In the html code on the category page is like this

```html
`{{site.url}} / {{page.url}}`в _config.yml, как это:`Постоянная ссылка: '/: категории /: название'`в браузере в строке url он будет отображаться без /index.html. Все как нужно. Например:`https://site.ru/blog/otzyvy/`Но в коде страницы это отображается так:`https://site.ru/blog/otzyvy/index.html`Как это можно исправить?
```

Comment: I moved the liquid code into a codeblock. Can further updated the formatting? This doesn't look anything like HTML.

Comment: the bigger part of code even does even not seems like code-

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a permalink setting to the page and make sure the path includes a trailing slash. If you remove the slash at the end, it would create a relative path with `index.html`.

category page:

```
---
permalink: /category/
---
```